# How do I filter both parents and children in a O(1) queries?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a pair of models that have a basic parent/child relationship. The child has a field `foo`. I want to make an SQLAlchemy query that will return all of the Parent objects that have children with foo matching a criteria. Along with those parents, I want to return the children, but only if they matched the filter criteria.

These are my models:

```
class Parent(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship('Child', backref='parent')

class Child(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(String(128))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), nullable=False)
```

Here is an example. Lets say I have parents `A`, and `B`. I have children `a1`, `a2`, `b1`, and `b2`. Child `a1` has `foo = 1`, `a2.foo = 2`, and so forth.

I want to make a query like "child.foo == 1", and get this data back:

```
[
    {
        id: 'A',
        children: ['a1'],
    },
    {
        id: 'B',
        children: ['b1'],
    }
]
```

Note that `a2` and `b2` are not included in the results.

Two ideas I have considered so far, but haven't worked out:

1. Select on the child, then build parent objects.

   I wasn't able to query fields on the parent when I did this, which is also required.
2. Select on the parents, then iterate through the matching parents and make more queries to gather matching children.

   This (appears) to require O(n) queries, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all you want from a single query, you need to use [`join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) and [`contains_eager()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager):

```py
q = session.query(Parent).\
    join(Parent.children).\
    options(contains_eager(Parent.children)).\
    filter(Child.foo == 1)
```